# Emacs: How to toggle Buffer-menu-files-only by default

Tags: emacs, elisp, buffer

In [`buff-menu+.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/buff-menu+.el) (and also in `buff-menu.el`) there is a function called `Buffer-menu-toggle-files-only` which sets the variable `Buffer-menu-files-only` to `t`/`nil`.

When showing the buffer list, I can toggle this with the key <kbd>T</kbd> so I can prevent non-file-buffers from being shown in the list. I would like to have this filter (files-only) set by default. How could I implement this in my `init.el` file?

I tried:

```
(add-hook 'buffer-menu-mode-hook 'Buffer-menu-toggle-files-only 1)
```

but when I then show the buffer list, it says:

> run-hooks: Wrong number of arguments:  #[(arg) "..." [arg Buffer-menu-files-only prefix-numeric-value 0 t revert-buffer] 2 578818 "P"], 0

Can anybody give me a hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
(add-hook 'buffer-menu-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (Buffer-menu-toggle-files-only 1)))
```

I don't use buffer-menu, so this is untested. But this is the form all my mode-hooks follow, and they all work.

Comment: Didn't work for me (GNU emacs 25.1.1).  I got a message in `*Messages*` as thought the option has been changed, but non-files are still shown.

Answer (score 2):

The mode hook suggestion should work fine.

Another way to go is this:

```
    (defun my-list-buffers ()
      (interactive)
      (list-buffers t))
```

Also, I assume you already know that <kbd>C-u C-x C-b</kbd> lists only file buffers.

Answer (score 2):

This works and makes exactly what you need.

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-b") 'my-buffer-menu)
(defun my-buffer-menu()
   (interactive)
   (buffer-menu)
   (Buffer-menu-toggle-files-only 1))
```

Comment: You can also just call `(buffer-menu 1)`, instead of toggling afterwards.

Comment: Also, calling `(buffer-menu-other-window 1)` mimics the default behaviour of splitting the window to show buffers.